# Netbeans 6.8 xdebug gives error “Can not debug missing index file index.php” in Zend Framework project

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, xdebug

My Xdebug is properly configured as I could see in phpinfo(). But when I debug a project a Netbeans6.8, I get “Can not debug missing index file index.php” warning. Then another bigger settings window opens up as in [this image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?2b3982f52d.png). And, yes, index.php file is there. It's not missing.

How can I fix it?

```
Apache web_root: e:\htdocs
Project homepage: e:\htdocs\sliksvn\version3\terminus3.0\public\
```

Comment: I have posted a step by step article for this issue. You can check it out at my blog http://blog.elinkmedia.net.au/2010/02/08/netbeans-debugger-with-zend-framework/

Answer (score 3):

NetBeans 7 with Drupal install required me to select the correct document root:

Project Properties > Sources > Web Root > folder with index.php